# Brainfuck try to - in a 0 cell

Tags: brainfuck

What happens in Brainfuck if I try to "-" in a cell that contains a 0?

`>-`

Also, what happens if I try to start a loop while pointing to a 0 cell?

`>[]`

Edit:
I forgot to mention it, but I'm trying to make an interpreter.
Here's a piece of code I was given to use as an example:

`;>;<[->++<][->++<]`

In the second loop, the cell pointed at is "0", so my program starts an infinite loop.

Comment: What happens when you try it by yourself?

Comment: @Progman sorry, I forgot to mention I was trying to make an interpreter.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/brain-lang/brainfuck/blob/master/brainfuck.md for a possible memory layout you can use?

Comment: @Progman Thank you very much.

Comment: this does'nt answer your questions, but whenever you see `][` in a brainfuck program, you know that the second loop is never executed. this simplifies your code example to `;>;<[->++<]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brainfuck is a very implementation dependent language.
Usually, Brainfuck cells hold values ranging from 0-255, so 8 bit unsigned integer values.
If you try to decrement a cell with a value of zero, as usually happens with computers you will perform an "underflow", meaning the value will go from 0 to 255. Similarly, if you try to increment a cell with a value of 255 - you will get 0.

Looping in brainfuck can be though of with this piece of pseudo code:
[SOME_CODE]
is like
while(*ptr!=0){SOME_CODE}

So long as you are not pointing at a cell with a value of 0 in the beginning of the loop, you run the code within the brackets, and repeat.

I suggest you take a look at https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of brainfuck will roll over from 0 to 255, and 255 to 0. Many programs will not work at all if they can't roll over.

In your program example, the ';' is not a command. It should probably be commas.